# get some value and move to other table mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

im trying to make a registration approval..when i click the button the registration will be approve and some data will be send to other table..i have 2 table..

> Blockquote

tblpartner

```
companyPassword
companyEmail
companyUsername
```

tbluser

```
username
password
email
role
```

the question is,what is my problem in my query? the data wont go to other table and i got a blank page after i clicked the approve button

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
    {   
$id = $_GET['id'];
if ( $stmt3 = $mysqli->query ( "INSERT INTO tbluser (username,  password,email,role = 1) SELECT companyUsername,companyPassword,companyEmail  FROM tblpartner WHERE companyId=?" ));
        }
```

Comment: Turn on your error reporting to see the problem. Also, `(username,  password,email,role = 1)` seems invalid.

Comment: yeah u're right..what is the correct way to insert the value 1 into column role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong is you're using a prepared statement with `query()`. This is how you do a prepared statement in mysqli (I am assuming `$id` is an integer for the sake of this example)

```
if ( $stmt3 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tbluser (username,  password,email,role) SELECT companyUsername,companyPassword,companyEmail, 1 FROM tblpartner WHERE companyId=?" )) {
   $stmt3->bind_param('i', $id);
   $stmt3->execute();
}
```

Comment: ty..it seems my role=1 is the problem..so how can i insert the value 1 into the tbluser?

Comment: it does't work..i got ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement. from the else statement

Comment: Bleh. I goofed. Try the fixed statement above